# Не выводится Notification

Tags: android, java, service

Есть код, который должен выводиться в статус баре через сервис, но он не выводится.   Посмотрите профи глазом, почему, а то запарился уже...

```
public class MyServiceNotificationLessons extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }
    void someTask()
    {}

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
    someTask();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        CharSequence date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if((date.equals("5.12.2014"))||(date.equals("6.12.2014"))||(date.equals("7.12.2014"))){

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
            CharSequence contentTitle = "Уважаемый пользователь! ";
            CharSequence contentText = "Будь здоров)))....";

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Notification ntf = new Notification(icon,contentTitle,when);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);

            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID,ntf);
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Все получилось! Действительно надо было все это запихать в onStartComand и логироваться начало как положено.... и сразу появилась ошибка:  https://yadi.sk/i/oF0zzB__dDQsp

Comment: Ну, судя по логам ошибка у вас в someTask(), а что там мы не знаем. Нотификация-то сработала?

Comment: Что значит не знаем! Знаем! Я в someTask() положил весь код, а в

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
    someTask();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
Видимо не правильно да?

Нотификация только логируется хорошо, но не срабатывает...

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "логгируется"? Я под этим понимаю что-то типа 

    Log.d("my_log_tag", "my log messege");

И что у вас собственно на 48 строчке, на коей приложение падает?

И вы точно приведённый мною в ответе код используете или тот код, что у вас в вопросе написан?

Comment: падает вот тут:  mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, ntf);

Comment: @sviter-pro, таки попробуйте мой код. Тот, что я в ответе привёл.

Comment: ваш код полностью логируется и когда приложение запущено, то оно выводит notification стандартных настроек, чтобы выключить на это приложение уведомления

Comment: @sviter-pro, должен признать, что я не понял, что вы сейчас хотели сказать, кроме того, что проблема решена приведённым мною кодом. 0_о

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте, есть ли у вас в манифесте объявление вашего сервиса.

**Обновление 1:**

Попробуйте заменить вот эти ваши строки кода

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 Notification ntf = new Notification(icon,contentTitle,when);

mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID,ntf);
```

на вот эти:

```
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), icon))
        .setContentText("Начинаю загрузку")
        .setContentTitle("Загрузка статей")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent).build();

        this.startForeground(10, notification);
```

Да, и попробуйте перенести код из onCreate в onStartComand

Comment: Конечно.... <service android:name="by.itstep.alarm.MyServiceNotificationLessons" />

Comment: @sviter-pro, обновил ответ;

Comment: Изменил для теста все это на время:CharSequence date = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "." + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 

if((date.equals("19.31")) || (date.equals("19.32")) || (date.equals("19.33"))) {  и все ровно не работает...(((

Comment: @sviter-pro, кажется, я понял, в чём дело. Месяцы при использовании Calendar.MONTH начинаются с 0. Замените "12" на "11" в месяце при проверке.

И прологгируйте ваш код. Заход по if условию у вас вообще происходит?

Comment: Да, и попробуйте перенести код из onCreate в onStartComand

Comment: И как вы код этот вызываете?

Comment: логгируется вроде https://yadi.sk/i/9aOyK_7mdDJU5

Comment: сразу с запуском активити! startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyServiceNotificationLessons.class));